# Azure devops missing artifacts menu

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

I've just register a free account on dev.azure.com. I created an Organization and projects on it. I don't see the Artifact menu item in the left hand side. From project's setting I don't see Artifact service in the list Azure DevOps services. Does it intend? or I am missing configuration? Or even I have to upgrade to paid plan to use artifacts functionality

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the Artifacts extension installed?

Comment: I don't know about Artifacts extension. I have never installed an extension to use Artifacts service. I don't see any extensions that mentioned by the Microsoft's document

Comment: Hi  Dan Nguyen, According to latest info, this issue has been mitigated. Please kindly check it in your organization. Sorry for any inconvenience.  Also updated the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

This is  a service side issue for partially organizations in some regions.

[Availability Degradation in accessing Artificats](https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/179906466)

According to latest info, this issue has been mitigated. Please kindly check it in your organization. Sorry for any inconvenience.

> **Final update**
>
> *Alejandro Oviedo Cruz, 3/17/2020, 8:45 AM*
>
> The issue has been mitigated. We apologize for the inconvenience
>   caused by this incident.